# How can I get the forward path in Struts

Tags: struts-1, action-mapping

In the below mentioned Project I want to retrieve below mentioned forward path marked in Yellow. Is it possible?
[image]

I have tried to do this - `String af = mapping.getPath();`

But this actually returns the below mentioned marked in Yellow.
[image]

I tried using `mapping.getPath();`

But it's actually returning Action path instead of the Forward path.

Comment: Don't post the code in images.

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: **Why** do you want this? It **sounds** like something bad is happening. In any case: `ActionMapping#findForward` returns the `ActionForward` associated w/ the name. The docs are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

To get the forward path from the action config you can use Struts API.

[`ActionMapping::findForward()`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/archive/trunk/struts-doc-1.1/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionMapping.html#findForward(java.lang.String)) returns the `ForwardConfig` object mapped to the action config or a global forward.

> Find and return the `ForwardConfig` instance defining how forwarding to the specified logical name should be handled. This is performed by checking local and then global configurations for the specified forwarding configuration. If no forwarding configuration can be found, return `null`.

Now, you can get the forward by name

```java
ActionForward forward = mapping.findForward("hello1");
String path = forward.getPath();
```